# no webpage was found for the web address in azure

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy spring boot app's war file to azure app service. It deploys successfully. But when I open the url, I get

```
This appname.azurewebsites.net page can’t be found.
```

`No web page was found for the web address:https://appname.azurewebsites.net/`.

I see the login page in `localhost:9001` but I get the 404 error mentioned above in azure. I do not know much of Spring. I am only trying to deploy the application. Is there some place I should specify what page should be served when that appname.azurewebsites.net is loaded?

It works in `localhost` though. What am I doing wrong?

**I have only uploaded the `war` file. I have not done anything else to host on azure's app service's tomcat.** Is there something else I should do to make it work on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Package your Spring Boot application as a JAR file. (you can use `<packaging>` element in pom.xml)
- Upload the JAR file to D:\home\site\wwwroot of the WebApp
- Rename the JAR file to, say, app.jar
- Create a web.config in the same location and add the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
                      arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\app.jar&quot;">
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```